macOS WireGuard not working for IPv6
Using wireguard-tools stable 1.0.20210914 from brew on macOS 14.5 May 31, 2024:
This package didn’t use to work at all, now it works for IPv4, but that’s of little help on a dual-stack IPv4 IPv6 mac. After aws malefactors started charging for IPv4 February 2024, it’s IPv6 everywhere. There is really no reason for IPv4 anymore
The following issues are identified:
IPv6 transport is not possible
[Peer]
Endpoint = [2001:4860:4860::8888]:1234

— the tool tries to route the IPv6 address via the IPv4 gateway
The tunnel fails to transfer IPv6 packets
route -n get -inet6 ::/1
ifconfig utun6 | egrep '\tinet'    
nping -6 --tcp-connect --count 1 --dest-port 443 2001:4860:4860::8888
TCP connection attempts: 1 | Successful connections: 0 | Failed: 1 (100.00%)

Server’s DNS server setting are not used
scutil --dns
# nothing

An Address IPv6 gets /64 CIDR, on Linux it’s /128
Address = fde0:1234::

What gives?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
